# SQL DimDate Week Sequence

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a sequence for week rankings so that it'll be easier to query dates.

Sample Data:

[image: Week Sequence]

So if i wanted to get the current week's data, i'll just go SELECT * FROM table WHERE Sequence = 0.

Problem: I'm unable to figure out the logic to create the sequence field value. I'm currently on a dead end. Please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: *I'm trying to create a sequence for week rankings so that it'll be easier to query dates.*: it will not necessarily make it easier. You might want to explain the *original* problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: You can always calculate the week end (or start - which is typically easier) based on `current_date`, e.g. in Postgres, you can use `date_trunc('week', current_date)` to get the start of the week. Other DBMS products have similar functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do the week sequence!

DATEDIFF(WEEK, DATEADD(day, 2-DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()), CONVERT(date,GETDATE())) , WeekStartDate)

Answer (score 0):

In MSSQL, the following approach would work.

```
SELECT WeekEndDate, 
CASE WHEN [definition]='Current Week' THEN 0 
ELSE 
CAST(SUBSTRING([definition], LEN([definition]),1) AS INT) END [SEQUENCE], 
[definition] FROM [YourTable]
```